# try exceptional and pass in python

Tags: python

```
no1=input("enter number 1=") 
no2=input("enter number 2=")

try: 
    one=int(no1) 
    two=int(no2) 
    print("the sum of:",one+two) 
    print("the div of:",one/two) 
    print("the sub of:",one-two) 
    print("the mul of:",one*two) 
except ZeroDivisionError: 
    print("0 cannot be divid")
```

While I am trying to give `no1=100` and `no2=0`, the result I'm getting is only the sum of no1+no2 and `ZeroDivisionError`. I also need the subtraction and multiplication results in the same python file.

Comment: Put the subtraction and multiplication *before* the division.

Comment: Just put the try/except around the division attempt. You should also allow for the possibility that the inputs might not be convertible to *int*

Answer (score 0):

You should put your try/except block on your division only like so:

```py
no1=input("enter number 1=")
no2=input("enter number 2=")

one=int(no1)
two=int(no2)

print("the sum of:",one+two)

try:
    print("the div of:",one/two)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("0 cannot be divid")

print("the sub of:",one-two)
print("the mul of:",one*two)
```

You could also put the division after the rest of the operations like so:

```py
try:
    print("the sum of:",one+two)
    print("the sub of:",one-two)
    print("the mul of:",one*two)
    print("the div of:",one/two)   
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("0 cannot be divid")
```

That being said, since you're working with try/except blocks, you should consider putting one around your str to int conversion lines, in case your user didn't input a number.

All in all, I think your code should look like this :

```py
no1=input("enter number 1=")
no2=input("enter number 2=")

try:
    one=int(no1)
    two=int(no2)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter two integers")
    quit()

print("the sum of:",one+two)

try:
    print("the div of:",one/two)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("0 cannot be divid")

print("the sub of:",one-two)
print("the mul of:",one*two)
```

Comment: If either of the inputs cause ValueError this will still try to perform the calculations

Comment: @ArthurKing Thanks for pointing that out, is this better?

Comment: If the input is invalid, the entire program would terminate. Surely you'd want to offer the user the opportunity to try again

Comment: @ArthurKing you are making assumptions about the OP's intentions of the code. Maybe he wants to raise value error when the input is not correct. Maybe he doesn't want people to try again. Your comments should be directed toward the OP, not Shiverz. This answer solved the problem presented in the question from the onset, your critiques may harm his answer.

Comment: @ArthurKing Totally agree, however that seems like it drifts away from the initial question a bit too much, doesn't it? Adding a whole loop to allow the hypothetical user to try again, when the question is about try/except blocks? Plus who knows, maybe he doesn't want the users to try again (as another comment pointed out) ? All in all, I'm trying to stay focused on the question at hand, not on QOL details, while still implementing good practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order or use other exception handlers like **finally**

You are using exception only for division and u need to execute all other operation. You can try this way:-

```
no1=input("enter number 1=") 
no2=input("enter number 2=")

one=int(no1) 
two=int(no2)

try: 
         
    print("the div of:",one/two) 
     
except ZeroDivisionError: 
    print("0 cannot be divid")


finally:
    print("the sum of:",one+two)
    print("the sub of:",one-two) 
    print("the mul of:",one*two)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each one of them could be different functions. So, either you should create functions each one of like:

```
def sum(one, two):
    try:
        print("the sum of:", one + two)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
def sub(one, two):
    ...
def mul(one, two):
    ...
def div(one, two):
    ...
```

then you can use them in main block or you can use like this:

```
def main():
    one = int(input("enter number 1="))
    two = int(input("enter number 2="))

    try:
        print("the sum of:", one + two)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    try:
        print("the div of:", one / two)
    except Exception as e:
        if type(e).__name__ == "ZeroDivisionError":
            print("0 cannot be divid")
            pass
        else:
            print(e)

    try:
        print("the sub of:", one - two)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    try:
        print("the mul of:", one * two)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This my be an over complication... Also, you don't need `pass`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than bothering handling a ZeroDivisionError, why not just test the value for zero. For example:

```
while True:
    try:
        one = int(input('Enter value 1: '))
        two = int(input('Enter value 2: '))
        print(f'Sum={one+two}')
        print(f'Difference={one-two}')
        print(f'Product={one*two}')
        if two != 0:
            print(f'Quotient={one/two}')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input. Please try again')
```